# Parse xml response using retrofit

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, retrofit

i am unable to parse xml response using retrofit.
here is xml:

```
  <ossi>
      <eventdetail>
        <maps>
            <settings>...</settings>
            <map>...</map>
            <map>...</map>
        </maps>
     </eventdetail>
</ossi>
```

<------ EDIT ---------->

Here are models

```
    @Root(name = "ossi")
    public class RootEventDetail {
        @Element
        public EventDetail eventdetail;
    }

    public class EventDetail {
        @Element
        public General general;
        @ElementList
        public List<MenuItem> menu;
        @ElementList
        public List<WebViewItem> module_webview;

        //TODO how can i create model for Maps ??????
        @Element
        public Maps maps;
    }
public class Maps {
    @Element
    public MapSettings settings;
    @Element
    public List<EventMap> map;
}
```

How my model will look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What model architecture have you tried?

Comment: If you can not answer my question, why you are down voting without any reason.

Comment: Because before your edit it was just an xml example without any information on what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem. I used `inline` property to solve my issue.
Here is My Model:

```
public class Maps {
   @ElementList(inline = true ,required = false)
   public List<Map> map;
   @Element
   public Settings settings;
}
```

And Main class is:

```
 public class EventDetail {
    @Element
    public Maps maps;
}
```